# When a disability is seen as a good thing

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, psycholinguistics, disability-sensitive

***Ableism***

> discrimination or prejudice against individuals with disabilities

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ableism)

***Disableism*** (not found in MW)

> Disablism can be defined as discriminatory, oppressive, abusive behaviour arising from the belief that disabled people are inferior to others. Disablism refers to prejudice, stereotyping, or "institutional discrimination" against disabled people.

[Council of Europe](https://www.coe.int/en/web/compass/disability-and-disablism)

That sounds pretty much the same thing, with barely a sliver of light between them.

---

On  some of the **support groups** I have participated on, *ableism, ableist* also indicate *the belief that able people are superior to disabled people.*

***What word or phrase expresses the opposite viewpoint? That a disability is a positive thing, and even  sometimes makes the 'sufferer' appear  superior?***

"_________________ describes  the belief that her disability actually gave her an  advantage in life."

At this point I am thinking on [Greta Thunberg; "Super power"](https://www.theguardian.com/society/2019/nov/03/is-autism-a-superpower-greta-thunberg-and-others-think-it-can-be).

---

Remember Cat Steven's ***[Moon Shadow](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=moonshadow%20youtube)***?

> And if I ever lose my eyes 
> If my colours all run dry
> Yes, if I ever lose my eyes
> Oh, if, I won't have to cry no more

That is only looking on the positive side, a form of rationalization....I am looking for something more.
Surprisingly, the song does not ever reference loss of audition.

Context:

I used to have a friend called *Dreck*, and he was deaf and probably autistic. He once expressed to me that he could not stand being around a bunch of argumentative people, and was glad that he was deaf so that he could focus on the visual moment, and also consider patterns that others could not see. He called it "background noise", and said it was often intrusive.

---

[EDIT] ...to include a pertinent comment from @Joshua

> I don't know a word for this, but this definitely exists. The army **deliberately employs colorblind artillery spotters** because camouflage doesn't work on them because the dies no longer match the background.

I  did a bit of research on this, and it is a valid comment.

In fact. it quotes an article from TIME magazine going back to the beginning of WWII.

From [Color-Blindness.com](https://www.color-blindness.com/2010/06/02/color-blind-observers-for-national-defense/)...

> In a plane at Fort Sill, Okla. early this summer, an Air Corps observer was able to spot only ten of 40 camouflaged artillery fieldpieces on the ground. An observer of the Field Artillery in a plane spotted all 40 and accurately plotted their positions on his map. *The explanation: the artilleryman, selected under less rigorous examination than the Air Corps man, was colorblind.* Camouflage, designed to deceive the normal eye, fooled him not a whit.

I have also seen online posts saying that  although colorblindness is considered a disqualifying feature for NAVY SEALS, in fact some branches of the military actually hire people like this as snipers (provided they can score at least a  98 in the 10 ring).

More recently, I have seen other posts pointing out that **color-blind artillery spotters** in hovering helicopters  can often see differences in texture, and are considered more reliable. ...

Comment: ***Differently  abled*** has been used with no discrimination intent. https://www.lexico.com/definition/differently_abled

Comment: Not sure there is a term to indicate that “disability” is superior to “ability”. I think it all comes down to accepting diversity, rather than look for new forms of discrimination.

Comment: " look for new forms of discrimination. " is unfair.....this is more about empowerment, and  it is not a zero-sum game.

Comment: You're not looking for a negative term, are you? A lot of people (myself included) don't like "differently abled" (nor do I feel that it really expresses the desired meaning in practice). And there are certainly more negative terms out there.

Comment: @Laurel Indeed I am not.  This should be a more positive and  inclusive usage.

Comment: Her abilities allowed her to see what no one else could.

Comment: A *silver lining* is a positive aspect of an otherwise negative situation, and would fit Dreck's case.

Comment: I don't know a word for this, but this definitely exists. The army deliberately employs colorblind artillery spotters because camouflage doesn't work on them because the dies no longer match the background.

Comment: @Joshua I would really like to see a development of that idea.

Comment: We don't have a term to describe that sort of discrimination or prejudice, because society has a vested interest in pretending that nobody discriminates in such a manner or has such a superiority complex. This is why you only get words with positive connotations here, rather than ones that are actually effective for calling out bigots. Never mind that this demonstrably harms, for example, deaf people who get harassed by their peers if they seek treatments to become hearing again.

Comment: Yes, didn't Jesus once ask someone "Do you _want_ to be healed?" (though this could have been a beggar making what he perceived as easy money, steady income). It's a form of (at least perceived) natural compensation.

Comment: Is "Her (superiority definition) _______ gave her the ability to see what nobody else could see" meant to express the way some blind people develop better hearing, for instance?

Why Greta Thunberg? How does she come into this?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin Greta has often commented in interview that she considers her ASD to be a "super power", and not not a disability.

Comment: @Joshua TXS...your comment was such a good example I edited  to include it in the post...

Comment: Oh, thanks. If only I'd gone to the trouble looking that up!

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_: Anyway you should now understand why I could not develop the idea. I had found some of the source material but nothing that would qualify as an answer.

Comment: @Joshua Nevertheless, it was a great suggestion, and I will never forget....

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_, could your question be incorrectly constructed?
You start by supplying a couple of concepts describing *an attitude, a behaviour*, but then your question is illustrated with an example (_"Her (superiority definition) _______ gave her the ability to see what nobody else could see"_) about something apparently physical. Or is this just an example of someone being superior by being disabled and your intended question remains on the attitude/behaviour? I'm confused.

Comment: @RicardoGMC At first I was gonna dismiss your POV out of hand, but after looking more carefully I realized the sample sentence needed tweaking. Thank You...

Answer (score 11):

**Disability pride** seems like the most fitting term.

Kathleen R. Bogart Ph.D., who has facial paralysis caused by Moebius syndrome, explains in a [Psychology Today article](https://www.psychologytoday.com/us/blog/disability-is-diversity/202107/disability-pride-month-disability-is-broader-you-think):

> Like the early gay pride movement, disability pride is a radical shift from the typical way of thinking. Why would someone be proud of their disability? I, for example, am proud because my disability motivated me and gave me the specific expertise and lived experience to devote my career to improving quality of life for disabled people. I am proud because my face makes me distinctive—I have a tiny bit of celebrity status. People remember me after seeing me once, far better than I remember them. I am proud because my disability gives me a unique perspective of the world. I am proud because my disability has connected me to so many interesting and kind people in my disability community.

I saw ads for disability pride month 2022 on NatGeo, so it is out there. While it's still not a common expression (though a casual search tells me it's [at least 30 years old](https://www.disabled-world.com/definitions/disability-pride.php)), the meaning is very obvious thanks to LGBTQ pride month.

"Disability pride" is a positive term used by people with disabilities. Unlike other terms, using it doesn't make you seem opposed to the idea that disabled people can find things about their disabilities that enrich their lives, no hatred (of the abled) involved. And it doesn't sweep the difficulties of having a disability under the rug in a potentially patronizing way, unlike some other terms ("handicapable" or "differently abled", both of which are often labeled as ableist).

You can also see more specific versions used.
Compare [Deaf pride](https://www.ldpride.net/what-is-deaf-pride/) and [autistic pride](https://mindhacks.com/2005/11/23/autistic-pride/).

Answer (score 7):

[Neurodiversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurodiversity) and [neurodivergent](https://exceptionalindividuals.com/neurodiversity/) have positive connotations which might work in your example sentence.

- Neurodiversity:

  > “Neurodiverse” refers to a community of people whose members are
  > neurodivergent.
  >
  > Neurodiversity is an approach to education and ability that
  > supports
  > the fact that various neurological conditions are the effect of
  > normal
  > changes and variations in the human genome.
  >
  > ADHD, Autism, Dyspraxia, and Dyslexia all fall within the spectrum
  > of
  > “Neurodiversity” and are all neurodiverse conditions.
  >
  > Neuro-differences are recognised and appreciated as a social
  > category
  > similar to differences in ethnicity, sexual orientation, gender, or
  > ability.
  >
  > For example, a condition such as dyslexia is an integral part of a
  > person. To take away their dyslexia is to take away from the person.
- Neurodivergence

  > Noun: Cognitive functioning which is not considered "typical". For example, autistic, dyslexic, and dyspraxic people.
- Neurodivergent

  > Adjective: Describes people who have a neurodivergence.

(From [exceptionalindividuals.com](https://exceptionalindividuals.com/neurodiversity/))

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Could you take some time to type out or copy/paste the pertinent sections of the entries? Links rot over time...

Comment: @Cascabel: I temporarily added some content from the links into the answer. The OP can later edit in/out content as needed.

Comment: @Justin Above and beyond call of duty...

Comment: Note: Physical disabilities such as deafness or impaired movement aren't considered neurodivergence.

Comment: Agreed, Laurel.  There are tons of disabilities that don't fit this one.

Comment: People can become undyslexic. It is not always a brain condition.

Comment: @Laurel Nobody ever said they were. The OP was about disabled people, not about physically disabled people. This answer is relevant in that it acknowledges another sort of disability and thus another group of disabled people.

Answer (score 5):

**Appreciation of differences**

My son has Tourette Syndrome and obsessive-compulsive disorder.  He realized in middle school that the flip side of the misery caused by his intrusive thoughts is his off-beat sense of humor.  The connection he figured out is that he has a lot of imagination.  His imagination can lead him to unusual, entertaining ways of seeing things, but it can also go wild and lead to intrusive thoughts.

When possible, we like to speak of his *differences*, rather than his *disabilities*.  (Doesn't work when he's self-disclosing and asking for disability accommodations at work!)

I do like the proposed "Disability Pride," but "Appreciation of Differences" has the advantage that it doesn't include the word "disability," which can start to get a person down if overused.

When speaking of "differences," there's no judgment -- no assumption that the differences are necessarily bad or troublesome.  They may be troublesome in some contexts, but they can also be a plus, in others.

Variants: **awareness of differences, acceptance of differences**.

Comment: "Differences" seems like the appropriate word to me. It lacks judgement. She's different, which gives her an advantage in some situations

Comment: BTW, quite often there is an argument about the usage of the term "disabled"...it sounds offensive, but it was only until the last year that I had to accept the technical usage on support groups.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine_ - I prefer "with a disability" over "disabled."  It feels less of a global descriptor that way.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe there is a word for this yet, but poetry and literature are filled with examples of this theme. The Japanese have an art called [kintsugi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kintsugi), which is the practice of mending broken pottery with golden seams. It's all about how breakage and repair are proper parts of the beauty of an object, rather than something to be disguised. The Japanese also have [wabi-sabi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wabi-sabi), "a world view centered on the acceptance of transience and imperfection."

I recall two poems about this theme that are at least worth pondering as you search for a phrase. Their titles both serve well as a short-hand for the type of attitude you ask about: **"Nothing Worth Loving Isn't Askew"** and **"Pied Beauty"**

There's a song that I like related to this. It's called *Nothing Worth Loving Isn't Askew* by Lemon Demon.

Here's a link to the song: https://lemondemon.bandcamp.com/track/nothing-worth-loving-isnt-askew

and here are the lyrics:

> You are red and blue and green,
> Living like a living computer glitch.
> You could change to anything.
> All you gotta do is just hit the switch.
> You are muscle, flesh, and bone,
> Living in the land of automobiles.
> If you ever lose your shoes,
> All you gotta do is just click your heels.
> Symmetry’s overrated, methinks.
> Look at the scars all over the Sphinx.
> Do you know that when you blink,
> Each eye winks slightly out of sync?
> Symmetry’s overrated, methinks.
> Look at the scars all over the Sphinx.
> Even the planet spins with a tilt.
> Everybody’s built like a quilt.
> Have you heard the awful truth?
> Cursed asymmetricals go to hell.
> If you trip and lose a tooth,
> You gotta knock the other side out as well.
> Gouge both eyes out and you’ll see
> Empty sockets everywhere: self abyss.
> Fill them up with mercury
> So that I can see myself when we kiss.
> Symmetry’s overrated, methinks.
> Look at the scars all over the Sphinx.
> Even the planet spins with a tilt.
> Everybody’s built like a quilt.
> Trees in the forest fall to the side.
> Everybody’s got something to hide,
> Except for me and my suitcase
> Full of imperfections.
> If the court has no objections…
> Symmetry’s overrated, methinks.
> Look at the scars all over the Sphinx.
> I am lopsided, and so are you.
> Nothing worth loving isn’t askew.

I humbly propose the phrase "nothin' worth lovin' isn't askew" for your purposes.

There is also a much older poem about this called *Pied Beauty* by Gerard Manley Hopkins.

> Glory be to God for dappled things – 
>    For skies of couple-colour as a brinded cow; 
>           For rose-moles all in stipple upon trout that swim; 
> Fresh-firecoal chestnut-falls; finches’ wings; 
>     Landscape plotted and pieced – fold, fallow, and plough; 
>        And áll trádes, their gear and tackle and trim. 
> All things counter, original, spare, strange; 
>      Whatever is fickle, freckled (who knows how?) 
>          With swift, slow; sweet, sour; adazzle, dim; 
> He fathers-forth whose beauty is past change: 
>                                        Praise him. 
>  
> https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/44399/pied-beauty

Comment: Nice answer! I've included the poem "Pied Beauty" with the correct formatting 

Answer (score 2):

There is a [comics](https://twitter.com/abledsuper?lang=en) called **Super-abled** where the motto is "Disabled superheroes from disabled creators". It is a clever coinage; and coincidentally, there is the word **superable** (and the noun form **superability**) in English  meaning:

> capable of being overcome or conquered - *[MW](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superable)*

Double coincidentally, *superability* is used in the book *[Disability in Comic Books and Graphic Narratives](https://books.google.es/books?id=3rTtCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA7&lpg=PA7&dq=%22the%20superability%20of%22%20disabled&source=bl&ots=FB04ec_z2_&sig=ACfU3U0ZNeKJshPiZqeN7KFvNPuBEuxqNQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmwd_inqv4AhUQyYUKHeNKDjsQ6AF6BAgCEAM#v=snippet&q=superable&f=false)* edited by C. Foss, J. Gray, Zach Whalen:

> First, comics are fundementally representational media that incorporate images of the body in all ranges of ability, including (most visibly) the superability of empowered heroes.

Here is another usage of *superability* in the disability context from the book *[Disability, Deformity, and Disease in the Grimms' Fairy Tales](https://books.google.es/books?id=kCB-BAAAQBAJ&pg=PA147&dq=superability%20disability&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjb5KjLpav4AhUzgc4BHfegBbUQ6AF6BAgKEAI#v=onepage&q=superability&f=false)*
By Ann Schmiesing
:

> Nature rewards the disabled person with this compensatory superability. Disability and extraordinary ability are in this conception biologically intertwined and a gift of Nature or, in light of the Grimms' Calvinist worldview, God.

When I search *superability* and *disability* together, I find many related sources where the term *superability* is used in a way that empowers disabled people.

Note: *OED* lists both *superable* and *superability*; and adds that they are rare.

Comment: I will have a look...

Comment: Additionally, for the example sentence, I suggest _uniqueness_ which is a neutral word and can be used in any context. (and it is inclusive as everyone can be considered unique).

Answer (score 1):

There is no such word or term and I don't believe there ever will be.

I do believe the reason for that is that everyone knows disability is only ever a good thing if, for instance, a disabling wound means a soldier can go home from the war… in which case, the details matter more than the principle.

I'm sorry to have to point out that labelling people as "differently abled" instead of simply "disabled" doesn't at all overcome the idea that disabled people are somehow less worthy.

What it does, broadly, is make it very much harder to discuss the issue without appearing to give offence.

Comment: I appreciate your thoughts, and I wish you could develop them more. In the meantime, I understand your position and +1ed as they are germane to my query. Point in fact, I considered your answer as THE answer. . ..i.e. "There is no such word".